# Displaying Matplot on Flask

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

```
from flask import Flask
#from flask import render_template
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/plot')
def build_plot():

    img = io.BytesIO()

    y = [1,2,3,4,5]
    x = [0,2,1,3,4]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)
        def on_pick(event):
            leg = event.artist
            isVisible = leg.get_visible()

            graphs[leg].set_visible(not isVisible)
            leg.set_visible(not isVisible)
    mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
    plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()

    return '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format(plot_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

I have the following code. I just want to know if its possible to add a cursor hover for the points on the graph and a legend on/off picker when using matplot in flask application. I have the printing the matplot png that is being created, so I'm not sure if this is possible, I would appreciate any help.

The plot works when running in python file, it will open a gui with cursor and legend picker working. But when using with flask you can't use the cursor or legend picker.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give [Plotly](https://plotly.com/graphing-libraries/) a try.
I've added a small example based on a DataFrame below. The data is transferred to the template as JSON and displayed using SVG. The display of data associated with points by hovering with the mouse pointer and switching of data sets by clicking on the legend are activated by default.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import json, random
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Year': ['2012', '2014', '2016', '2018', '2020', '2022'],
        'Amount': [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(6)],
        'Count': [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(6)],
    })

    fig = px.line(df, x='Year', y=df.columns[1:])
    dat = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    return render_template('index.html', data=dat)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='chart'></div>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      ((data) => {
        Plotly.plot('chart', data, {})
      })({{ data | safe }});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```